# Overlay network performance issues with docker swarm

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

At present, we use docker network create of docker swarm to create a group of overlay networks, and then use docker service create to create a service cluster and join the network provided above. Nginx also joins the network above. The configuration of nginx is as follows:

```
location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    proxy_pass http://docker_service_name:8080;
}
```

Realize load balancing and dynamic capacity expansion through docker swarm. However, there is a problem here. For individual interfaces, the back-end processing time is 20ms from the log view, but the log view of nginx layer is 1.003s. Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: nginx log here ```{"@timestamp":"2019-12-18T20:50:23+08:00","reqTime":"1.091","respTime":"1.091","connectTime":"1.002","headerTime":"1.091","uip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","fip":"192.168.200.80","upServer":"172.21.19.85:8080","host":"172.18.0.6","domain":"xx.xxx.com","method":"POST","uri":"/uri","args":"-","size":202,"referer":"-","agent":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; FRD-AL10 Build/HUAWEIFRD-AL10)","reqId":"5ef0c29b77e2d5b232f0aae2d71c2ce7","status":"200"}```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sudo nsenter --net=/var/run/docker/netns/{your_load_balancer} sysctl -w net.ipv4.vs.conn_reuse_mode=0
sudo nsenter --net=/var/run/docker/netns/{your_load_balancer} sysctl -w net.ipv4.vs.expire_nodest_conn=1
```

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  core:
    image: nginx
    sysctls:
        - net.ipv4.vs.conn_reuse_mode=0
        - net.ipv4.vs.expire_nodest_conn=1
```

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35082

Answer (score 0):

From [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35082#issuecomment-696607578) in the issue [[SWARM] Very poor performance for ingress network with lots of parallel requests](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35082#issuecomment-696607578) this lag issue seems solved for kernel version over 5.4.

(Side note: This kernel is the one used in Ubuntu 20.04)